# How do I get Thingsboard Cloud Integration to return a 200 or 201 and not 204 Http response?

Tags: thingsboard

I have created a ThingsBoard http integration with uplink converter and no downlink converter. When I use curl to test the endpoint, it returns Http Error 500 with the error details. When it is successful, it returns a 204 with no data. My device however interprets 204 as an error ( and I cannot change that ). Is there a way to configure ThingsBoard Http Integration to return a 201 or 200 rather than a 204 or to even have some data with the 204 response?

Answer (score 0):

Oh. There is a configuration for it in the advanced tab when setting up the Integration.